# Can you change the colour of frosted glass easily?

Tags: paint, glass

I Have a frosted white glass table that i want to change the colour to a black frosted look, can i paint over the white? Would this work or how else can i turn it into a black frosted glass table?

Comment: I wonder if some sort of dye would work, e.g. like permanent marker but on a larger scale...

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not easily changed. I strongly suspect that you'd be better off living with it white, or trading it for a black one, as any paint-based solution will be far inferior to actual colored glass in appearance and durability.

The best possible paint option might be to paint the bottom black, but it may not give the look you want - however, painting the top black will give you simply the look a black painted surface, not a "frosted glass surface" at all.

You might want to use plasti-dip (or something similar) if experimenting with paint - it can be peeled off most surfaces if you change your mind.

But I'd suggest leaving it alone as being the most likely to succeed.

Comment: Or, to test, try taping black construction paper to the bottom and see if it's at all all close to what you want.

Comment: I also vote for painting the back side of the glass. This can lead to some very elegant looks for either frosted or unfrosted glass.

Comment: @MichaelKaras, sounds like maybe you have done this.  When you paint the frosted side, does it still end up looking frosted or does the paint fill in the texture and just give a glossy painted look?

Comment: Painting any glass makes the painted side look like a coat of paint!! Where you get the looks is to paint the back side. If you use the paint on the smooth non etched side then the etching on the opposite side will appear dark because no light passes through from the far side. Then you can look into edge lighting the glass for interesting effects. Edge lighting in the modern day with LED strips can be cool. It can make etched glass take on colors. Of course a lot depends upon if the etching is just simple surface frosting or if the glass was etched to 3D effects.